# Return row number if text exist

Tags: jquery

I want to get the row number if table contains the text 'Storage'

The table is this:

```
Product    | Apple | Lenovo | HTC  | Samsung | LG
Camera     | 20MP  | 12MP   | 22MP | 20MP    | 20MP
RAM        | 4GB   | 4GB    | 4GB  | 3GB     | 2GB
Storage    | 32GB  | 32GB   | 32GB | 32GB    | 32GB
Expandable | No    | Yes    | No   | Yes     | Yes
Contract   | No    | Yes    | Same | Yes     | Yes
```

In this case the code should return the value '4' but my below doesn't work

```
var tid=$("tr td:contains('Storage')").index();
```

Could you please help me to correct my code?. I am just a beginner in programming, so kindly help me.

Comment: Are you trying to query a database table directly? Or have you actually output this table in the HTML DOM somewhere? If you have, can you please post your relevant HTML as well, thus forming a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: It is a dynamic HTML table generated by a Survey analyzing software. It generates 8 HTML tables on 8 different screens. When it shows a table on a screen I want to fetch the row number based on the specific text and want to do some calculation at run time. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

**[jQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)** only work on **perfectly-formed** HTML.
The problem is probably in the construction of your table.

For example, if you omit `<table>`, the `tr td:contains` selector **won't** work:

```js
var tid = $("tr td:contains('Storage')").index();
console.log(tid);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tr>
  <td>Storage</td>
</tr>
```

But if you include `<table>`, the `tr td:contains` selector **will** work:

```js
var tid = $("tr td:contains('Storage')").index();
console.log(tid);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Storage</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that the jQuery is **identical** in both snippets above, and there is a `<td>` element within a `<tr>` element in each that contains the text `Storage`.

The second snippet explicitly specifies `<tbody>`, though note that the parser will automatically assume you are wanting to utilise `<tbody>` if you don't manually specify it, and add it in for you.

Hope this helps! :)